# How come my else statement does not execute

Tags: python

I new at python. I would like to understand why my else statement does not work? The else statement should return "Zero", but it returns "None" instead.

```
def number_group(number):
  if number > 0:
    return "Positive"
  elif number < 0:
    return "Negative"
  else:
   "Zero"

print(number_group(10)) #Should be Positive
print(number_group(-5)) #Should be Negative
print(number_group(0)) #Should be Zero
```

[image]

Comment: You are missing a `return` before "Zero".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to add return in the last line

```
# you wrote "zero"
# you should use
else:
    return "Zero"
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the return statement:

```
def number_group(number):
  if number > 0:
    return "Positive"
  elif number < 0:
    return "Negative"
  else:
    return "Zero"

print(number_group(10)) #Should be Positive
print(number_group(-5)) #Should be Negative
print(number_group(0)) #Should be Zero
```